# Округление числа в большую сторону, кратную определенному числу

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток всем. Что-то не могу сообразить, как сделать данное округление.

Пробовал делать проверку на остаток от деления (%), если оно равно 0. то дальше при помощи ceil() округляем в большую сторону. Получается не то, что нужно :)

```
if (($val_get % $pack_val) == 0) $val_get = ceil($val_get/$pack_val); else $val_get = $pack_val;
```

Вот что я писал. Нужно предусмотреть тот случай, что если `$pack_val > $val_get`. Остаток получается равен `$val_get` в случае если `$pack_val > $val_get`. Помогите, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что такое $pack_val и $val_get - не понял.

```
//$base - число, кратно которому округляем.
//$num - вводимое число    
if($base>0){
  return ceil($num/$base)*$base;
}else{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: if ($val_get % $pack_val != 0) $val_get = ($val_get - $val_get%$pack_val) + $pack_val; else $val_get = $pack_val;

вот такой вариант придумал) инет умпал и не мог написать